# How can I replace dashboard.css and dashboard.min.css (not add new css)

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I want to replace `dashboard.css` and `dashboard.min.css` (not add new css)

I know how to add new css but I need to remove those styles.

I tried `wp_dequeue_style`  but nothing happens

Comment: How and where are those style enqueued, dashboard.css is not a WP core stylesheet if I am correct

Comment: When did you dequeue the style? There's an order to things, e.g. if you dequeue something before it's added there's nothing to dequeue yet

Answer (score 0):

Because `wp_dequeue_style` should run after `wp_enqueue_style` ran. So you need to call it with a lower priority so your hook can be applied after it has been enqueued.

try this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_dequeue_scripts', 99 );
function my_dequeue_scripts(){

  wp_dequeue_style( 'dashboard' );

}
```